# Analysing Captured ESP8266 Captured Frame

Tags: networking, esp8266, wifi, arduino-esp8266

So I've captured

> C40B2050000000000000000094000000XXXXXXXXXXXX0000000000000400A0E7FF0700000000000003000000640021040100200000000400A0E7FF07

I have some known data (my computer's MAC address shown in X's) and I'm pretty sure this is ADDR1 based on looking at the positions of MAC addresses in many captured frames.

I'm trying to figure out what type of frame it is using 802.11 frame layout.

[image: 802.11 frame layout]

And this is how I interpreted the packet:

```
frameControl:9400
frameControlBinary:1001 0100 0000 0000
frameTypeBinary:01
frameSubTypeBinary:1001
frameType:Control
frameSubType:Reserved
toDs||fromDs:00
sourceAddress:000000000000
destinationAddress:C48E8FF2E8B9
bssidAddress:0400A0E7FF07
```

But according to this table, that frametype is 'reserved', which I assume means it is not a valid frame type.

[image: table of frame types]

Comment: That control subtype, `1001`, is actually a `Block Ack`. You seem to be looking at an old table.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be working with obsolete information. IEEE 802.11™-2012 shows the current definitions:

[image]